# Parsing text on Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, parsing, text

I have a small problem out there in Ruby on Rails app.
You see I have the correspondence, one user can send a message to another and so on....
But then there is the reply, when the original text is taken and there should be ">" on the beggining of the each line in the text field (I am using ckeditor in this textfield), which helps me to put the blockquote there when showing it then.
So the example would be:

The original message I received:

```
hi there,
howareyouhowareyouhowareyouhowareyouhowareyou howareyou howareyou howareyouhowareyouhowareyouhowareyou howareyou howareyou howareyou
howareyouhowareyouhowareyouhowareyouhowareyouhowareyou howareyouhowareyouhowareyou
howareyouhowareyouhowareyou howareyouhowareyou howareyou howareyou howareyou
howareyou howareyou howareyou howareyou howareyou howareyou howareyou howareyou
```

The reply should then be like:

```
hi sure I am fine

>hi there,
>howareyouhowareyouhowareyouhowareyouhowareyou howareyou howareyou 
>howareyouhowareyouhowareyouhowareyou howareyou howareyou howareyou
>howareyouhowareyouhowareyouhowareyouhowareyouhowareyou
>howareyouhowareyouhowareyou howareyouhowareyouhowareyou
>howareyouhowareyou howareyou howareyou howareyou howareyou 
>howareyou howareyou howareyou howareyou howareyou howareyou 
>howareyou
```

I hope you see what I did there, my main problem is how to cut the text to fit the line and at the same time not to cut words into pieces at the end of line (so just cut it if there is a whitespace), I know (obviously) how to do it when there is return at the end of each line, but its not of any help now, because nobody puts return on each and every line :(

(sry I left out '>' on every beggining of the line in the reply like I was mentioning, because here '>' is a blockquote and is therefore converted and not visible)

Hope you guys understand my problem and have some soolution or maybe some helpful links, because I am trying, but it is still not working properly.... or not at all right now :(

Thanks for your help, I appreciate it

PS: I found the perfect one on xing.com, and I have to keep in mind that those reply can go deeper than one reply :P thx

Comment: How about a newline after 78 chars?

Comment: you see thats what I am trying to tell you, I cannot divide words wherever i want :( thats the problem here :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the method [word_wrap](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-word_wrap)  is what you are looking for?

You may split the text into lines, and **then** each line split into shorter lines, using `word_wrap`. Then, if you detect a line that is **still longer** than your expected length *(and this is possible if someone forgets to press 'space')*, split these lines exactly after 'n' characters. Optionally you may enhance the third step by writing some more intelligent procedure of splitting words.